# Sqlite Trigger Doesn't accept datetime object

Tags: python, database, datetime, sqlite

the following is my SQLite Query

```
  sql = '''CREATE TRIGGER autodelete AFTER INSERT ON syslog
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM syslog) > '''+self.size_limit+'''
                BEGIN
                DELETE  from syslog where time < ( select time from syslog limit -1 offset '''+str(self.co)+''');
                INSERT INTO syslog (time,loglevel,logcode,logmessage) values
 ('''+datetime.now()+''',"Information","I1800","message");
                END'''
```

When I execute this query from my Python code it gives me the following error

```
Coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, **datetime.datetime**
```

found

But when I execute the insert query

```
self.cur.execute('INSERT INTO syslog (time, loglevel, logcode, logmessage) values (?, ?, ?, ?)', (datetime.now(), loglevel, logcode, logmessage))
```

This works well with `datetime.now()`,
But when I execute the trigger SQL this problem of datetime appears , it says

```
Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found
```

Why does it happen only in the first query and now the second query ( insert query )

I also tried `unicode(datetime.now())` and `str(datetime.now())` 
But none of them are working .

Comment: Are you sure you want to add the same timestamp every time the trigger fires? Why don't you use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: datetime.now() would give me a different timestamp every time right ?

Comment: Every time you build the `sql` string. If you create the trigger just once, every insert will have the same timestamp.

Comment: Can you show me where it is written ? because when i add insert after trigger it gives the current time because i pass that

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code but if you create the trigger once and in the way you've stated above, it will always insert the same timestamp. It seems like you are trying something like this: `i=1; t='i='+str(i); i=i+1; print t`. If you want the trigger to insert the current time: `INSERT INTO syslog (time, ...) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ...)`.